# Intersection of an open neigbourhood of a mobius strip and and a disk

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have seen that the  real projective plane of dimension 2 can be expressed as a union of a disk and a mobius strip but what I don't understand is that why their intersection is a cylinder?  Can anyone please explain
Thanks in advance

Comment: imagine gluing the edge of the disk to the edge of the mobius strip. This is how you construct, in some sense, $\mathbb{R}P^2$. I'm sure there is an algebraic way to explain this through simplicial homology. The intersection of a disk and a mobius strip however depends on their embedding in space. The two are not naturally a part of the other (well, a disk could be seen naturally part of the mobius strip but not visa versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are glued on their respective boundaries, both of which have a circle as their boundary (which is good because otherwise we wouldn't be able to glue them together in a nice way). You want them to intersect on a nice subset. Normally this will mean either just gluing the boundary circles together in which case their intersection is a circle (up to homeomorphism) or you let them overlap a little, in which case the intersection would be the same circle but it has been 'thickened up' a little bit. In other words the intersection is homeomorphic to $S^1\times [0,1]$ (or $S^1\times (0,1)$ depending on if your disk and Mobius strip include their boundaries or not).